# Conditionally Showing Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a very basic order form (and am still in the design phase), and have a place where their is potential to input into about 14 different drop down lists.  Well *IF* possible, I would not want to show all 14 drop down lists, I would only want to show the 1st and if it is filled in, then show the 2nd, and if it is filled in show the 3rd etc etc...

I am using `C#` and `webforms` and am creating the drop down lists using `asp.net` -- using that as a basis is their a Javascript function or C# syntax or someway of achieving the above?  This is a snippet of what I have (I am not showing full syntax as it literally just repeats itself for each drop down)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="test">
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="labelone" runat="server" Text="Label One:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td class="style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="278px" 
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="labeltwo" runat="server" Text="Label Two:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist2" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="45px"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="Label OneOne:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td class="style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist33" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="278px" 
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text="Label TwoTwo:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist4" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="45px"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick script for dependency enabling / disabling.

Use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    new dependencyChain($("#ImNumberTwo"), [ $("#ImNumberOne") ]);
    new dependencyChain($("#ImNumberThree"), [ $("#ImNumberOne"), $("#ImNumberTwo") ]);
});
```

```js
var dependencyChain = function(el, dependencies) {
    var self = this;
    var element = el;
    this.dependencies = dependencies;
    
    this.init = function() {
        for (var i in this.dependencies) {
            var dependency = this.dependencies[i];
            dependency.on("change", function() {
                self.checkDependencies();
            });
        }
        
        self.checkDependencies();
    }
                      
    this.checkDependencies = function() {
        var disable = false;
        for (var i in this.dependencies) {
            var dependency = this.dependencies[i];
             
            if (dependency.val() == "") {
                disable = true;
            }
        }
        element.prop("disabled", disable);
        if (disable) {
            element.hide();
        }
        else {
            element.show();
        }
    }
    
    this.init();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 new dependencyChain($("#ImNumberTwo"), [ $("#ImNumberOne") ]);
 new dependencyChain($("#ImNumberThree"), [ $("#ImNumberOne"), $("#ImNumberTwo") ]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ImNumberOne">
    <option></option>
    <option>EEEeeeeeeeey</option>
</select>
<select id="ImNumberTwo">
    <option></option>
    <option>there!</option>
</select>
<select id="ImNumberThree">
    <option></option>
    <option>there!</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet all 3 drop down lists are shown?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight Updated to hide the element. It was just enabling / disabling them before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdownlist_SelectionChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdownlist_SelectionChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dropdownlist_SelectionChanged" />

protected void Dropdownlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var ddl = sender as DropDownList;

    switch(ddl.ID) {
        case "ddl1":
            ddl2.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "ddl2":
            ddl3.Visible = true;
            break;
        // and so on
    }
}
```